# MessageConversionException when trying to serialize a List of Avro SpecificRecords and split them with @Splitter

Tags: groovy, rabbitmq, avro, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Cloud Stream (Elmhurst Release) Splitter with a RabbitMQ binder. I'm trying to update it so that it will use Avro schema for the payloads. I'm getting a conversion exception which makes it look like the Avro converter isn't getting invoked, and the JSON Converter picks up the message and trips on it.

> Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not write JSON: Not a map: {"type":"record","name":"SkinnyMessage","namespace":"com.example.avro","doc":"Light message for passing references to Message objects","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"string"},{"name":"guid","type":"string"}]} (through reference chain: com.example.avro.SkinnyMessage["schema"]->org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema["valueType"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Not a map: {"type":"record","name":"SkinnyMessage","namespace":"com.example.avro","doc":"Light message for passing references to Message objects","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"string"},{"name":"guid","type":"string"}]} (through reference chain: com.example.avro.SkinnyMessage["schema"]->org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema["valueType"])

I've confirmed that I can create objects and serialize them to-disk using the generated Avro class (maven-avro plugin), so that part seems right. I've converted the project to Java from Groovy and still get the same error, so I think that's ruled out, too.

Here's the Avro Schema:

```
{
  "namespace": "com.example.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "SkinnyMessage",
  "doc": "Light message for passing references to Message objects",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "guid",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the relevant part of the class:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
class PagingQueryProcessorApplication {
    @Timed(value = 'paging.query')
    @Splitter(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
    List<SkinnyMessage> queryExecutor(def trigger){
        log.debug 'Building query'
        def query = queryConfiguration.buildQuery().toUriString()

        log.info "Executing query: ${query}"
        def response = service.getRecordings(query)

        log.info "Returning response collection: ${response.body.content.size()}"
        // We build a slim notification on each of the query responses
        def skinnyMessages = response.body.content.collect{
            new SkinnyMessage(it.getLink('self').getHref(), it.content.guid)
        }
        skinnyMessages
    }
...
}
```

Edit: When I step through with a debugger, I can see that the AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter fails the `canConvertTo(payload, headers)` call because the `mimeType` in the headers is `application/json` and not `application/*+avro`, so it continues trying the rest of the converter chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I build a message and set an avro content-type header on it, that seems to work, but that seems like a hack.

```
List<Message<SkinnyMessage>> skinnyMessages = response.body.content.collect{
    MessageBuilder.withPayload(
            new SkinnyMessage(it.getLink('self').getHref(), it.content.recordingGuid))
            .setHeader('contentType', 'application/*+avro')
            .build()
}
```

Creates messages which look right in RabbitMQ UI:

> contentType:  application/vnd.skinnymessage.v1+avro
>   correlationId:    f8be74d6-f780-efcc-295d-338a8b7f2ea0
>   content_type: application/octet-stream
>   Payload
>   96 bytes
>   Encoding: string
>
> thttps://example.com/message/2597061H9a688e40-3e30-4b17-80e9-cf4f897e8a91

If I understand the docs correctly though, this should happen transparently from the setting in the application.yml: (as in [Schema Registry Samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/Elmhurst/schema-registry-samples/schema-registry-vanilla/producer1/src/main/resources/application.yml)):

`spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          contentType: application/*+avro`

Comment: No, that is not a hack by any means and in fact exactly what needs to happen. Otherwise how do we know which converter to apply. The default CT is `application/json`, hence the generic json converter takes priority.
Please read this section for more details https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#content-type-management

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky isn’t the Avro converter supposed to take precedence when it sees content-type:application/*+avro in the properties?

Comment: I am confused. If your message contains CT header, then it is used. If not then it falls back to the one set via binding properties (as above) and only then it falls back to the default one.

Comment: Ah, I've been working through variations in a sample project -- the issue seems to be that the Avro converter isn't activated for Integration-annotated methods. As soon as I switched from @Transformer/@Splitter to @StreamListener/@SendTo, it started working.

Comment: Ok, that reads like a bug to me. Glad that you were able to work around it by using   @StreamListener, but please raise the issue anyway so we can address it https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues

Comment: Opened https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1461 -- Accepting this answer in the meantime.